# is there any advantage in using ' ?: Operator ' vs an if else statement?

Tags: c#

Is it simply a matter of preference or is there any good reason to use one over the other.. performance wise?? :

```
string x = (serialNbr != "")?serialNbr:String.Empty;
```

vs.

```
string x;
if(serialNbr == "")
{
    x = String.Empty;
}
else
{
    x = serialNbr;
}
```

Comment: performance shouldn't be your first concern.  sometimes the ?: operator makes code more easy to read, and that's good enough.

Comment: Pro: ?: Can be used straight in assignments which can make code more terse and concise. Con: ?: Can be used straight in assignments which can make code more complex if there are multiple levels of embedded conditions.